# initializing array with max elements passed by function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am doing work for school, I'm supposed to write a function that accepts the number of employees that work for a company and returns the value to main.

Then I am to write a function called by main that accepts the number of employees that work for the company. I am then supposed to ask the number of days each employee missed in that function and return the total of the days missed.

I'm having a problem on the second part. I am trying to create an array with the number of employees as the max number of elements, but I keep getting an error about the variable I put in between the brackets  not being a constant even though it is!

I am a little foggy on arrays and this is meant as a refresher course. If I could just create an array I would use a for loop to go through each element and store the number of days missed in each.

Thanks for any help,
Aaron

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int noOfEmployees();
int daysAbsent(int);

int main(){
    int employees;

    employees = noOfEmployees();
    daysAbsent(employees);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int noOfEmployees(){
    int employees;
    cout<<"Please enter number of employees/n";
    cin>>employees;
    return employees;
}

int daysAbsent(int employees){
    const int max = employees;
    int daysMissed;
    int workers [max];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int workers[max];` is not legal C++, because the size of the array (`max`) is not a compile-time constant. Even though the variable `max` is declared to be constant after construction, it is constructed at runtime from the argument to `daysAbsent`, and so the size is not known at compile-time.

If you want a variable sized array, try `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
int daysAbsent(int employees) {
    const int max = employees;
    int daysMissed;
    std::vector<int> workers(max);
    cin>>daysMissed;
    //Use workers somewhere in here
}
```

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>` at the top of the file?

Comment: Nope! Thanks, I will try this, haven't gotten to vectors yet :p

Answer (score 3):

> […] I keep getting an error about the variable I put in between the brackets not being a constant even though it is!

It needs to be a *compile-time* constant; that is, the compiler needs to be able to silently replace `int workers [max]` with something like `int workers [10]`. In your design, it depends on the argument to the function, which isn't known until run-time.

There are a few different ways to handle this, but the best is probably to use a `std::vector<int>` rather than an `int[]`:

```
std::vector<int> workers;
```

(being sure to `#include <vector>` at the top of your program).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the variable needs to be a compile time constant, which your value is not. For example a literal integral type or an `enum`.

In this case however it's easy to use `vector` instead:

```
int daysAbsent(int employees) {
    const int max = employees;
    int daysMissed;
    std::vector<int> workers(max);
    cin>>daysMissed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an array of variable size in C++. You'll have to allocate the memory dynamically. Use `new` operator for that:

```
int* workers = new int[max];
```

When you're finished, you should release the memory to prevent memory leak, using `delete` operator:

```
delete [] workers;
```

Comment: Do not do this. The correct way to avoid a memory leak is to wrap the resource in a class that manages its lifetime, which you then instantiate with automatic storage duration. For most purposes, the `std::vector` from the standard library is an appropriate class which does this for dynamic arrays.